# Trigger "Expression is always true" warning on a helper function

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have a function called `isDefined`, which is implemented like so:

```js
export function isDefined<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
    return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}
```

Functionality, it works. But, there's one small thing that I try to accomplis. Let's take this code for example:

```js
const a: number | null | undefined = 1;

if (a !== undefined && a !== null) {
  // a is inferred here as `number`
  ...

  if (a !== undefined) {
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ tslint/eslint will throw the following warning: 
    // "Expression is always true. (strict-type-predicates)"

  }
}
```

Since I've already checked if a is defined, the lint will throw a warning that stating that again would be redundant.

If I try to replace it with `isDefined`, No warning will be thrown:

```js
if (isDefined(a)) {
  // a is inferred here as `number`
  ...

  if (isDefined(a)) {
    // linter throws nothing
  }
}
```

I wasn't able to reproduce it in codesandbox since I cannot configure the eslint, but this is the code:

```js
export function isDefined<T>(value: T): value is NonNullable<T> {
  return value !== undefined && value !== null;
}

function linterWillThrowWarning<T>(value: T | null | undefined) {
  if (value !== null && value !== undefined) {
    if (value !== null) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}

function linterWontThrowWarning<T>(value: T | null | undefined) {
  if (isDefined(value)) {
    if (isDefined(value)) { // (I want it to throw)
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be beyond the capabilities of a linter. I'm not sure if it gets type information from TS in order to know you're narrowing an already narrowed type. The first version can be statically analysed but the latter requires knowledge available to the compiler.

Comment: The linter doesn't know whether the function has side-effects or not; nor whether it is deterministic (and a user-defined type guard is not required to be pure or deterministic). It would be unusual, but not impossible, for the second call to return a different result, even if there is no code in between the two calls to `isDefined` which could possibly change `value`.

Comment: @kaya3 are you sure the linter knows about type guards at all?

Comment: @VLAZ That depends on the linter; `eslint` presumably doesn't, `tslint` might (I don't use it so I can't really say), the question says one but the tag says the other. If the linter doesn't know about type guards then the same issues apply; it cannot assume that a call to the same function with the same argument will return the same result and not have side-effects.

Comment: @kaya3 well, TSLint has been discontinued in favour of ESLint. My impression is that the two would have comparable features and taking away the compiler information going from TSLint to ESLint seems like a *huge* downgrade. So, I suspect neither really takes into account the type system. But I'm really not familiar with TSLint, so I might be wrong. I'm fairly confident that ESLint only does static analysis of the AST parsed from the file, doesn't take into account additional details.

Comment: @VLAZ That sounds likely, yes. Since I don't know about the behaviour of particular linters, my comment was more about why a hypothetical linter might intentionally not complain about the example in the question.

Comment: I  tagged both eslint and tslint since I wanted to know if there's any solution for this. Anyhow, I get your points. Thanks.